# Adding a new DNS server with systemd-resolved

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, systemd, internal-dns

To access other machines on my network by their name, I have to add the following two lines to my `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
search foo.local
nameserver 192.168.X.Y
```

But any changes I make do not persist across reboots.

This is the content of my `/etc/resolv.conf`, which is actually a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

I read the manuals mentioned above as well as the [ArchWiki on systemd-resolved](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved), but I could not figure out what needs to be done.

This is a Ubuntu 18.04 VM (on a Ubuntu 18.04 host).

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (ens2)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.122.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using systemd-resolved instead of NetworkManager, add the following line to
the very beginning to `/etc/resolv.conf.head`:

/etc/resolv.conf.head

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Prevent NetworkManager from modifying `/etc/resolv.conf` and leave everything to
systemd-resolved by adding the following line under the `[main]` section of
`/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
dns=none
```

As a last step you will have to restart `systemd-resolved`.

```
host> sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
host> sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved
```

Once done, you can verify if the new DNS settings are effective:

```
host> systemd-resolve --status
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`resolvectl`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/resolvectl.1.html) command. Specifically, the `dns` and `domain` subcommands can be used to set the `nameserver` and `search` domains respectively.

```
resolvectl dns eth0 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
resolvectl domain eth0 my.domain.com
```

Use `resolvectl` by itself to show the current DNS configuration.

```
$ resolvectl
Link 2 (eth0)
Current DNS Server: <main dns ip>
       DNS Servers: <list of extra dns ips>
        DNS Domain: <list of search domains>
```